# Echo form input in php

Tags: php, jquery

I've written these 2 simple php code, to test php with jQuery:

FILE aaa.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="bbb.php" method="POST">
    <p>Il tuo Nome: <input type="text" name="name" value="" /></p>
    <p>La tua et: <input type="text" name="age" value ="" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit"></p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

FILE bbb.php

```
Ciao <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
La tua eta e di <?php echo (int)$_POST['age']; ?> anni.
```

But it doesn't work, because I don't receive any variable on bbb.php.

Could someone explain why?

Comment: mind removing the CAPS from the title? it's called "shouting" and nobody likes getting shouted at, do you? I didn't think so ;-)

Comment: what you posted has nothing to do with jQuery. Look at your HTML source, what does it show... "code"?

Comment: sorry Fred, i'll remeber for the next time

Comment: Fred do yuo know why this post methond dosen't post nothing?
I don't understand....

Comment: again; look at your HTML source after you hit submit. what does it show you? Something like `<?php .... ?>` ?

Comment: do I have to ask you a 3rd time?

Comment: Generally, if your file aaa is in a different folder to bbb.php it won't work however in this instance it should give you a 404 error. I think Fred has hit the nail on the head with this one that your php is being determined as html

Comment: ok, you're no longer responding and I have moved on, ciao!

Comment: Is on the same folder

Comment: and after click submit, browser got to bbb.php page but dosen't show nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using jquery mobile without ajax form submission, you need to data-ajax="false" in form.

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST" data-ajax="false">
```